# hdfs + what would be the main cause of UNDER REPLICA blocks

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, ambari, hdp

I'm just curious to know what would be the main cause of UNDER REPLICA blocks

We have ambari cluster with HDP version - `2.6.5`

Number of data nodes machines are - `5`

[image]

As it would always have at least three copies, I thought this would be hard to happen (but happens)

If HDFS can't create one copy or detects corruption, wouldn't it try to recover by copying a good one into another DataNode?

Or once a file was properly created in HDFS, does it never check if file is corrupted or not until HDFS is restarted?

*To fix the under replica we can use the following steps:*

```
su hdfs
hdfs fsck / | grep 'Under replicated' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' >> /tmp/under_replicated_files 
for hdfsfile in `cat /tmp/under_replicated_files`; do echo "Fixing $hdfsfile :" ;  hadoop fs -setrep 3 $hdfsfile; done
```

how `hadoop fs -setrep 3`  , is works?